# Laravel Show error Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated

Tags: php, laravel, http, wamp

i am working on api in laravel 5.4 when i run it it give this error

> Deprecated:  Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To avoid this warning set 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' in php.ini and use the php://input stream instead. in Unknown on line

i edited php.ini file also set this always_populate_raw_post_data = -1 and uncomment it
and i also add this line in php.ini "parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"), $_POST)"

but error still show on my side...
and 5.6.25 is php version
how this error will remove???
thank you

Comment: What's you php version

Comment: 5.6..25 is a php version

Comment: Did you add the line `parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"), $_POST)` to your php.ini-file??

Comment: Did you restart the web server after updating your php.ini? I bet not if you added the parse_str line and didn't have an issue.

Comment: yes i added this line parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"), $_POST) in php.ini before if...mean before this line always_populate_raw_post_data = -1

Comment: php.ini is a ini file (settings file), not a php file. You can't add PHP code in it.

Comment: yes #aynber i restarted the web server again and again after adding this line prse line

Comment: then #magnus on which file i added this code??

Comment: Was it the correct ini-file? Feels like you should have gotten a bunch or errors when PHP tries to parse that file. The code you added goes in your app, not in php.ini...

Comment: yes #magnus its a correct php.ini file located in bin/php/pjp5.6.25

Comment: then how this error will remove?

Comment: You **did not edit the correct `php.ini`** file. See the DUP for how to edit the right `php.ini` file